# How do get multicast to work on a Cisco AP1240?

Tags: cisco, wifi, ios, multicast

I have a Cisco AP1142N in standalone mode acting as a simple AP. On the wired segment of the LAN, there is an Apple TV that is used to mirror laptop screens to a large TV screen.

As long as clients are in the wired LAN, they can see and stream to the Apple TV without issue. It doesn't work when they are associated with the WLAN, though.

It appears to me that this is a problem with the multicast mDNS queries not being able to cross segments. Interestingly, according to `iperf`, multicast traffic from the WiFi to the wired network is working, but not the other way around.

I stumbled upon some posts ([example](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2014818)) on the Cisco support forum indicating that IGMP snooping should be deactivated to make multicast "just work", so I did that:

```
>show ip igmp snooping 
Global IGMP Snooping configuration:
-----------------------------------
IGMP snooping             : Disabled
IGMPv3 snooping           : Disabled
Report suppression        : Disabled
TCN solicit query         : Disabled
TCN flood query count     : 2

Vlan 10:
--------
IGMP snooping                       : Disabled
IGMPv2 immediate leave              : Disabled
Explicit host tracking              : Enabled
Multicast router learning mode      : pim-dvmrp
CGMP interoperability mode          : IGMP_ONLY

Vlan 99:
--------
IGMP snooping                       : Disabled
IGMPv2 immediate leave              : Disabled
Explicit host tracking              : Enabled
Multicast router learning mode      : pim-dvmrp
CGMP interoperability mode          : IGMP_ONLY
```

But the situation is still the same: WiFi to wired multicast works, the other way around does not; thus the WiFi users cannot see the Apple TV.

What other settings do I need to change in order to get mDNS working across the access point?

Comment: Are the apple Tv and the access point on the same vlan?

Comment: Yes, they are both on VLAN10. VLAN99 is just a guest SSID. Sorry, should have clarified that.